# Name this green giant insect hanging on the wall

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This Insect was found on the wall of the Party Hall, Where I went to my Girlfriend's birthday party. This insect looks very greeny. I am in India.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply found ***Parasanaa donovani***, Which is the large bush-cricket found in India and various countries in Southeast Asia.

[image]

Comment: "Simply"? I'd be very excited to see one of those!